# Django DoesNotExist at /admin/login/ while working with Django forms-builder

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I was using my http://localhost:8000/admin perfectly before but then I installed `django-forms-builder` package and created a form. Since then I was getting this error while trying to access `/admin`.

```
DoesNotExist at /admin/login/
Site matching query does not exist.
```

Then I opened `setting.py` and set `SITE_ID = 1`. This fixed the `/admin` problem but now when I go to http://localhost:8000/forms/test it says

[image]

Now when I comment the `SITE_ID=1` in `settings.py` this forms works normally but then I can't access `/admin`. When I use the `/admin` to access the form using the following way it redirects me to `http://example.com/forms/test`

[image]

Please guide me where I am making trouble?

Comment: Did you complete steps described here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/sites/#enabling-the-sites-framework

Comment: Yes I did `python manage.py makemigrations` and then `python manage.py migrate`.

Comment: you have example.com as your domain. Look at the sites app and replace

Comment: @Goran please elaborate how should I replace? Also please guide why it started happening now and why django wasn't behaving like that before?

Comment: @muazfaiz you have sites app in django admin. Replace example.com with your localhost:8000

Comment: Thanks @Goran. I just did that and it works. I appreciate if you can explain in the answer why it started happening suddenly and was not doing any problems before. I can then mark your answer as correct. It might help others in the future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is a continuation of the conversation in the comments of the question.

The issue is connected with `Django sites framework`, not with `django-forms-builder`. Just replace default value “example.com” with your domain. For the development you need to use your develoment URL.

You experienced an issue because your newly installed app probably use [redirects app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/redirects/#module-django.contrib.redirects) or `django.contrib.contenttypes.views.shortcut`, and they uses `django.contrib.sites` to works as expected.

Also on the admin framework, the **"view on site"** link uses the current Site to work out the domain for the site that it will redirect to.

To become more familiar with sites framework visit [How Django uses the sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/sites/#how-django-uses-the-sites-framework).